# PermissionError: [Errno 1] jupyter notebook by Anaconda

Tags: macos, jupyter-notebook, errno, permissionerror

My laptop is MacBook M1 and I'm using Anaconda-Navigator to launch Jupyter Notebook. When I first started using it, there was a notification asking me to give permission to the files but I accidentally clicked denied. Now I can't access the file I needed. May I know how can I change the permission for my file?

I have tried enabling full disk access for Anaconda in security & privacy but it doesn't work. I can't find settings in Jupyter Notebook too as it is just a website.

Answer (score 0):

Simply uninstall Anaconda-Navigator and remove all unwanted logs from your system then reinstall that and at the time of installing don't forget to give the file permission.

Comment: i have been trying for few times and it still does not work ;-;